# Alineamiento en Card

Tags: html5, bootstrap-4

¿Cómo puedo alinear las `card` en Bootstrap 4? Pero no alinear cada `card` como tal, sino más bien, su texto para que todas las `card` queden del mismo `size`.

[image: no existe un alineamiento dentro de las CARD, es decir en el texto de ellas]

```html
<!-- Inicio de las Tarjetas-->
<section id="tarjetas" class="container">
  <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
            <div class="card" style="width: 18rem; font-family: arial;">
              <img src="img\watermelon.jpg" class="card-img-top" alt="...">
                <div class="card-body text-center text-justify-center">
                <h5 class="card-title">Watermelon</h5>
                <p class="card-text">Watermelon is high in vitamins A and C. It’s also rich in some important antioxidants, including lycopene, carotenoids and cucurbitacin E. Some of watermelon’s antioxidants have been studied for their anti-cancer effects..</p>
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-success">Learn +</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>


        <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
            <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
              <img src="img\pineapple3.jpg" class="card-img-top" alt="...">
                <div class="card-body text-center">
                <h5 class="card-title">Pineapple</h5>
                <p class="card-text">Among the tropical fruits, pineapple is a nutrition superstar. 
                One cup (237 ml) of pineapple provides 131% of the Reference Daily Intake (RDI) for vitamin C and 76% of the RDI for manganese.</p>
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-success">Learn +</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>


        <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
            <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
              <img src="img\avocado.jpg" class="card-img-top" alt="...">
                <div class="card-body text-center">
                <h5 class="card-title">Avocado</h5>
                <p class="card-text">avocado is low in carbs and comprised mainly of healthy fats. The majority of the fat in avocado is oleic acid, a monounsaturated fat linked to reduced inflammation and better heart health. In addition to healthy fats, avocados are loaded with potassium, fiber and magnesium.</p>
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-success">Learn +</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
  </div>
</section>

<!-- Fin de las Tarjetas-->
```

Answer (score 4):

Prueba usando la clase `h-100` junto a la clase `card`, así:

```
<div class="card h-100" style="width: 18rem; font-family: arial;">
```

Espero te sirva, te dejo una referencia a la [documentación](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/sizing/).